# Texture glitch in Cycles in Render Preview and Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

So a while back I modeled a stand which I appended for a project I'm currently working on. However when I go into render preview mode using cycles or I just render it I have this weird glitch but it only oocurs on some parts of the mesh.
Link to blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MvqYj1DIEeWSpPfDdvBLUpY1IIRWc74N/view?usp=sharing

Here are some screenshots:

Render preview (Cycles)
[image]

As you can see in the middle parts of the drawer it seems to be bugging out.

,

Material preview

[image]

In material preview you can see the texture as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some overlapping meshes. Delete one of them and the problem will be fixed:[image]

Comment: Thanks! that was it. Embarassing how I didn't notice tho :-) Cheers mate!

Comment: No problem !) Have fun with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, subsurface was the problem, if there is no subsurface then it works.